# Intent not getting fired sometimes

Tags: android, rx-java2, mosby

I have the following code:

```
public class CheckoutPresenter extends CheckinOutPresenter {

    @Inject
    public CheckoutPresenter(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread, OnlineBookingRepository onlineBookingRepository, OfflineBookingRepository offlineBookingRepository, ImageRepository imageRepository) {
        super(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread, onlineBookingRepository, offlineBookingRepository, imageRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindIntents() {
        Observable<CheckinOutViewState> checkinViewStateObservable =
                intent(CheckinOutView::fetchLocalCheckin)
                        .switchMap(uuid -> offlineBookingRepository.fetchCheckoutById(uuid, false)) <-- Here sometimes get called, sometimes not
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                        .map(CheckinOutViewState.SuccessLocalFetch::new)
                        .cast(CheckinOutViewState.class)
                        .onErrorReturn(CheckinOutViewState.ErrorStateOut::new)
                        .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler());

        Observable<CheckinOutViewState> sendCheckin =
                intent(CheckinOutView::sendCheckin)
                        .switchMap(checkinIntent -> imageRepository.saveImage(checkinIntent.getFilename(), checkinIntent.getSignature())
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                                .filter(cnhImageResponse -> cnhImageResponse.getLinks() != null)
                                .switchMap(response ->  {
                                    CheckinOutCommand command = checkinIntent.getCheckinOutCommand();
                                    command.setSignatureUrlImage(response.getLinks().getUrl());
                                    return onlineBookingRepository.doCheckout(command).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor));
                                })
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                                .map(CheckinOutViewState.SentSuccessfuly::new)
                                .cast(CheckinOutViewState.class)
                                .startWith(new CheckinOutViewState.LoadingStateOut())
                                .doOnError(error -> offlineBookingRepository.doCheckout(checkinIntent.getCheckinOutCommand()))
                                .doOnComplete(() -> offlineBookingRepository.deleteCheckoutById(checkinIntent.getCheckinOutCommand().getBookingId(), false))
                                .onErrorReturn(CheckinOutViewState.ErrorStateOut::new))
                        .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler());

        subscribeViewState(Observable.merge(checkinViewStateObservable, sendCheckin), CheckinOutView::render);
    }

}
```

which inherits from:

```
public abstract class CheckinOutPresenter extends MviBasePresenter<CheckinOutView, CheckinOutViewState> {

    protected final ThreadExecutor threadExecutor;
    protected final PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread;
    protected final OnlineBookingRepository onlineBookingRepository;
    protected final OfflineBookingRepository offlineBookingRepository;
    protected final ImageRepository imageRepository;

    CheckinOutPresenter(ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread, OnlineBookingRepository onlineBookingRepository, OfflineBookingRepository offlineBookingRepository, ImageRepository imageRepository) {
        this.threadExecutor = threadExecutor;
        this.postExecutionThread = postExecutionThread;
        this.onlineBookingRepository = onlineBookingRepository;
        this.offlineBookingRepository = offlineBookingRepository;
        this.imageRepository = imageRepository;
    }

}

@Override
    public Observable<String> fetchLocalCheckin() {
        return Observable.just(booking.getBookingId());
    }
```

But the problem is, sometimes the fetchLocalCheckin is fired, sometimes not.
What am I doing wrong here ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Observable<String> fetchLocalCheckin() {
     return Observable.just(booking.getBookingId());
}
```

`Observable.just(...)`. This one triggers exactly one time `onNext()` followed immediately by a `onComplete()`. Since Mosby's `MviBasePresenter` follows the Reactive contract which basically says that once a `onComplete()` event is received the whole stream "finishes", that means  the `CheckinOutView::fetchLocalCheckin` only triggers exactly one time and cannot be invoked a second time (because `onComplete()` already has been triggered).

So if you want to trigger multiple times this intent, don't use `Observable.just()` but rather `PublishSubject` or `PublishRelay`.

i.e. with your case, this one will only ever trigger the first time your View layer (Fragment, Activity, ViewGroup) has been created, but no second time, i.e. after screen orientation changes, because the first time it has been created `Observale.just()` triggers `onComplete()` which prevents MviBasePresenter from accepting future events.

Comment: The problem is, sometimes it works sometimes not, but why does that happen ? Because this intent is called when I create the fragment, that's why I'm having trouble figuring out the problem.

Comment: So are you saying that intent is sometimes not triggered on first time your fragment is created?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's proprietary.

Comment: Exactly, on the first open of the fragment sometimes it work, sometimes not, but the Observable.just is always called, regardless of if it works or not

Comment: In that case it might be a bug. Please file an issue on github, with code of your Presenter and View (Fragment, only intent part)

Comment: Sure, I'll open a new issue. Thanks for your help !